# Printing out the input of a linked list [C]

Tags: c, linked-list

I wrote a linked list and managed to add filesupport to it. Now there is a problem with the command prompt output. The last `pokemon->name` and `pokemon->number` is getting outputted cryptic. Somehow I assume I did a mistake in saving the last batch of data into memory, because it is actually correctly saved into the file.

Here is the code (input testing after the code)

```
pokemonPtr addPokemon(void){

FILE *filePtr;

//filePtr = fopen ("pokedex.txt", "a");

//if (filePtr == NULL){
    filePtr = fopen ("pokedex.txt","w");
//}

pokemonPtr firstPtr;
pokemonPtr thisPokemon;
firstPtr = NULL;

firstPtr = (pokemon *) malloc(sizeof(pokemon));
firstPtr->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * POKEMON_LENGTH);

printf ("Enter the name of the Pokemon.\n");
scanf("%s",firstPtr->name);
fprintf(filePtr, "Pokemon Name:%s    ", firstPtr->name);
getchar();
printf ("Enter the number of the Pokemon.\n");
scanf("%d",&firstPtr->number);
fprintf(filePtr, "Pokemon Nummer:%d\n", firstPtr->number);



firstPtr->next = (pokemon *) malloc(sizeof(pokemon));

thisPokemon = firstPtr->next;

int i = 0;

while (i < 2){

    thisPokemon->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * POKEMON_LENGTH);

    printf ("Enter the name of the Pokemon.\n");
    scanf("%s",thisPokemon->name);
    fprintf(filePtr, "Pokemon Name:%s    ", thisPokemon->name);
    printf ("Enter the number of the Pokemon.\n");
    scanf("%d",&thisPokemon->number);
    fprintf(filePtr, "Pokemon Nummer:%d\n", thisPokemon->number);

    thisPokemon->next =(pokemon *) malloc (sizeof(pokemon));
    thisPokemon = thisPokemon->next;

    i++;

}

thisPokemon->next = NULL;

fclose (filePtr);

return firstPtr;

}

void showPokemon(pokemonPtr firstPtr){

printf ("Name:   %s\n"
        "Nummer: %d\n", firstPtr->name, firstPtr->number);

pokemonPtr thisPokemon = firstPtr->next;

while (thisPokemon != NULL){

    printf ("Name:   %s\n"
            "Nummer: %d\n", thisPokemon->name, thisPokemon->number);

    thisPokemon = thisPokemon->next;
}


}
```

The input I tried was:

> Pokemon Name:dudu    Pokemon Nummer:3 
>   Pokemon Name:dada    Pokemon Nummer:3
>   Pokemon Name:dudi    Pokemon Nummer:23
>   The output in cmd was:
>   Name:   dudu
>   Nummer: 3
>   Name:   dada
>   Nummer: 3
>   Name:   dudi
>   Nummer: 23
>   Name:   Ót
>   Nummer: 7607776

What happened here?

Comment: oh sry, I will add the missing function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The last `pokemon->name` and `pokemon->number` is getting outputted
>   cryptic

**Reason:**

The **reason** why you get a 4<sup>th</sup> node is because **you are creating an empty node at the end of each iteration and then filling it up at the start of each iteration**...

- So during the last iteration you create an empty node and get out of the loop.
- to this empty node's `next` member you assign the `NULL`.
- Therefore you end up getting four nodes printed in which the final one is empty.

---

**Solution :**

The **solution** to this problem is to assign memory at the beginning as the other answer suggests.But,

> *In your code, you take the pain of writing everything separately for head node and rest of the nodes in both the functions*

**You can achieve what you want to do by using a single loop...**

**here I've provided a function in which you can do that within a single loop:**

```
pokemonPtr addPokemon(void){

FILE *filePtr;

filePtr = fopen ("pokedex.txt","w");

pokemonPtr firstPtr;
pokemonPtr thisPokemon;

int i;

for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) //single loop!
{
    if(i==0)//head node
    {
        thisPokemon =(pokemon *) malloc (sizeof(pokemon));
        firstPtr=thisPokemon;
    }
    else //any other node
    {
        thisPokemon->next =(pokemon *) malloc (sizeof(pokemon));
        thisPokemon=thisPokemon->next;
    }

    //first allocation of memory takes place
    thisPokemon->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * POKEMON_LENGTH);

    //then you enter details
    printf ("Enter the name of the Pokemon.\n");
    scanf("%s",thisPokemon->name);
    fprintf(filePtr, "Pokemon Name:%s    ", thisPokemon->name);
    printf ("Enter the number of the Pokemon.\n");
    scanf("%d",&thisPokemon->number);
    fprintf(filePtr, "Pokemon Nummer:%d\n", thisPokemon->number);

    //no memory allocated at the end
}

thisPokemon->next=NULL; // the next of last entered node points NULL

fclose (filePtr);

return firstPtr;

}
```

---

Apart from this similarly, i'd like to **suggest** you to use the showPokemon() function this way:

```
void showPokemon(pokemonPtr firstPtr){

pokemonPtr thisPokemon = firstPtr;

while (thisPokemon != NULL)
{

    printf ("Name:   %s\n"
            "Nummer: %d\n", thisPokemon->name, thisPokemon->number);

    thisPokemon = thisPokemon->next;
}


}
```

**you need not print separately for first node and rest of the nodes :)**

Comment: this is a very clear explanation, thanks a lot! I will take my time and work through it!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem is in the way you build your linked list - it is trivial as soon as you execute the code under a debugger -> you should really learn to do that ;-)

You correctly save the head in `firstPtr`, but you start you loop with an empty but allready created and link element. So here is what happens in `addPokemon`:

- initial part: alloc a new item and read its values allocate a new item and link it to first: first(dudu) -> this(empty)
- first pass in loop: first(dudu) -> dada -> empty
- second pass in loop: first(dudu) -> dada -> dudi -> empty
- after end of loop, you put a null, but one step too far: first(dudu) -> dada-> dudi -> empty -> NULL

How to fix:

You should allocate a new item inside the loop just before storing values in it and start the loop with thisPokemon pointing to firstPokemon:

```
...
firstPtr->next = NULL;

thisPokemon = firstPtr;

int i = 0;

while (i < 2){

    thisPokemon->next =(pokemon *) malloc (sizeof(pokemon));
    thisPokemon = thisPokemon->next;
    thisPokemon->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * POKEMON_LENGTH);

    printf ("Enter the name of the Pokemon.\n");
    scanf("%s",thisPokemon->name);
    fprintf(filePtr, "Pokemon Name:%s    ", thisPokemon->name);
    printf ("Enter the number of the Pokemon.\n");
    scanf("%d",&thisPokemon->number);
    fprintf(filePtr, "Pokemon Nummer:%d\n", thisPokemon->number);

    i++;

}
...
```

Comment: good explanation sir. But, I think it's advisable to say to OP to use the same loop for operating upon all the nodes rather than operating upon head node and rest of the nodes separately :)

Comment: thank you very much, this is a really nice explanation. I wish I could upvote you!